# Hyper-V virtual machines become disjoined from domain regularly

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain, hyper-v, domain-controller

I have a server running Windows Server 2008 Enterprise SP1 that has a Hyper-V manager with two virtual machines. The problem that I am facing is that on any given day either one of the virtual machines becomes disjoined from our domain. This is a recurring issue and sometimes happens multiple times per day.

Any thoughts on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

**UPDATE**

The virtual machines are randomly losing their connection to our domain controller. So, for example, when restarting a Windows service on one of the virtual machines that uses domain credentials the service fails to start.

As a resolution, we have to join the virtual machine to the local computer domain, restart, join it to our domain, then restart again. This process is very disruptive and time consuming.

**UPDATE 2**

Technically, restarting the virtual machines does not fix the problem, only after rejoining it to the domain.

I will check to see if the virtual machine is still visible from AD when it gets disjoined again.

The event logs don't show much useful information. They show when the Windows services stop due to domain credentials not working.

**UPDATE 3**

I found this interesting entry in the event log. This entry was created right before the Windows services stopped and domain authentication ceased:

> Event ID: 1006
>
> Source: GroupPolicy
>
> Error: The processing of Group Policy failed. Windows could not authenticate to the Active Directory service on a domain controller. (LDAP Bind function call failed). Look
>   in the details tab for error code and description.

**UPDATE 4**

<strike>Looks like when either of the virtual machines becomes dis-joined from the domain, it's not visible from AD on the domain controller.</strike>

**UPDATE 5**

Upon further investigation it looks like the virtual machines are indeed visible in AD on the DC when this "dis-joining" occurs. However, this issue seems to be plaguing our other servers.

A common symptom of this "dis-joining" issue is receiving the following error when logging in using domain credentials, e.g. DOMAIN\username instead of LOCAL\username:

> The trust relationship between this workstation and the primary domain failed.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? What is "disjoined"? What happens exactly? What's your network configuration? More info please.

Comment: @MichelZ: Updated my question with more details. Not sure how much more details I can give.

Comment: What error messages do you see when this problem presents itself? What do the event logs say? What does `"randomly losing their connection to our domain controller"` mean exactly? Can it not ping the DC? Can it not authenticate?

Comment: Does a restart fix it? This is not a disjoint then.

Comment: this doesn't make sense: "that has two Hyper-V virtual hosts". do you mean 2 hyper-v guests?

Comment: so when this happens does the server object disappear from AD?

Comment: I've voted to close this and downvoted. It's been edited two times by the OP since we've asked for more specific details and a better description of the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion and incorrect terminology. There are two virtual _machines_ hosted on the Hyper-V server.

Comment: @MDMarra: Really? I'm sorry for messing up the terminology. I have edited it because I want to add more details as you all have requested. Why all the hate.

Comment: My voting has nothing to do with your terminology. You seem to have ignored or missed the comments asking for a more accurate description of the problem as well as event log entries that correspond to this issue. At least three people have left comments asking for information that is not included in your question. What you've provided is essentially meaningless in its current form.

Comment: @MDMarra: I'm researching the event logs right now and will provide a better update soon.

Comment: The network card in the server, what chip is it?

Comment: How did you create these VMs?  Where they completely separate clean installs of the OS?  Or did you clone them somehow?

Comment: @ChrisS: The chip is a BCM5708C.

Comment: @Zoredache: I inherited this server so as far as I can tell these VMs were fresh installs.

Comment: @tonyroth: Yes, the VM is not visible in AD when this happens.

Answer (score 3):

> **UPDATE 4**
>
> Looks like when either of the virtual machines becomes dis-joined from the domain, it's not visible from AD on the domain controller.

That means that someone or something is deleting the computer objects from your AD. Check for scheduled tasks, "cleanup" scripts, other admins, etc. A client-side problem will not remove the object from AD unless someone with privileged credentials unjoins the machine from the domain.

If worse comes to worse, you can turn on [auditing](http://blogs.technet.com/b/abizerh/archive/2010/05/27/tracing-down-user-and-computer-account-deletion-in-active-directory.aspx) and see what account is being used to delete these objects.

Answer (score 0):

Without anymore information, this really sounds like an issue that could be caused by the VM guest's being clones of one another.  If you shut down one of the guest VM's for a while (if you can), it would be interesting to see if the other one experiences the problem.

Comment: How would this be the cause of the problem? In all likelihood, It would present itself immediately if that was the case, not after a day and only if both machines had the same name and were joined to the same domain. Having the same local SID doesn't cause any problems, contrary to popular belief.

Comment: @MDMarra, after doing some more research I think you may be right, the problem should present itself immediately if it was a machine SID or sysprep issue. That being said, I've experienced a lot of weird behaivor with Windows 7 being cloned incorrectly that presents itself days or weeks later. I still might shut down the other VM to see what happens if he can.

Comment: @JustinBuchanan: Shutting down either VM is not an option. The next time one goes down I will try to see if I can see it from the domain controller.

Comment: @BryanRoth, once this issue presents itself, do the VM's still have transport with other hosts on the network or the Internet? Are there any more event log messages in the System event log other than the GroupPolicy one you mentioned? I would expect to see some messages from Netlogon/Winlogon/Kerberos if it is some kind of AD problem as opposed to a network issue.